# Simple animation causes flickering screen in c++

Tags: c++, windows, animation

I am trying to use the following code to simulate a simple text-loading animation:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i ++)
{
    system("cls");

    cout<<disp;
    disp += ".";
    Sleep(100);
}
system("cls");
```

However, the screen keeps blinking when I'm doing this. Is there a better way I can do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this would do the same thing your code is trying to do:

```
system("cls");
for (int i=0; i<15; ++i)
{
    cout << '.';
    Sleep(100);
}
system("cls");
```

Comment: Thanks, it's reduced now, but it still flickers during start and end. Is there any other replacement for this or do I just have to use it?

Comment: @rtuner: If you want to get rid of it entirely, you'll need to move away from the console(no more cout or printf) and start using some kind of graphics API that does double-buffering.  It's not going to be a quick fix, it's a steep learning curve from what you've been doing so far, but it's worth it.  Here's a great library to start with: http://www.sfml-dev.org/

Comment: @rtuner: Actually, if you simply take out the `system("cls")`, that will get rid of the flicker.  But then of course, the screen will not be cleared.  Is the screen clearing an essential part of your program? (it's highly un-portable by the way, but I realize at your stage, you're probably not too concerned about that at this point)